# Pusher dotnet api for .NET Web Api Core and WPF

Tags: pusher

I'm trying to integrate Pusher instead of SignalR into my .NET application. My application consists of .NET Core Web Api and WPF clients and they need to communicate via Web Sockets (besides obvious REST communication).

The thing is I'm confused which library I'm supposed to use. Like there's an official .NET library which is called [pusher-http-dotnet](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-http-dotnet). But its nuget package is called PusherServer which is very confusing. Is it supposed to work only as a server solution? Can I use it for WPF clients? Seems like not as I see a lot of Triggering examples and no Subscribing ones.

There's another library under Pusher-Community account which is called [pusher-websocket-dotnet](https://github.com/pusher-community/pusher-websocket-dotnet) and its nuget package is published under name PusherClient. The good news it seems to have some subscribing api. The bad news is it has quite serious issues without any response.

I'm totally confused with Pusher .NET libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pusher libraries are split in to http libraries, for publishing events and authenticating private channels (usually running on a server); and websocket libraries, for subscribing to channels and binding to events (usually running on the client). [See here](https://pusher.com/docs/libraries) for a comprehensive list. [pusher-http-dotnet](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-http-dotnet) falls in to the former category, so doesn't provide subscribing functionality. [pusher-websocket-dotnet](https://github.com/pusher-community/pusher-websocket-dotnet) is the websocket counterpart (with subscribing etc.) – it is a community library, and as a result development on it is slow and it is not as polished as the official libraries, but many people use it without issue.